# Nested Fragments with v13 of the Android Support Library

Tags: android

I am trying to use nested fragments with the v13 Android support library and I am unable to call getParentFragment(). I have use the v4 support library with nested fragments and have successfully made calls to getParentFragment.

Does the v13 Android support library support nested fragments? Or, can you only use nested fragments with the v4 support library, or if the app targets API 17?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use v13 unless you know it's fine for you:

> This library is designed to be used for Android 3.2 (API level 13) and
>   higher. It adds support for the Fragment user interface pattern with
>   the (FragmentCompat) class and additional fragment support classes For
>   more information about fragments, see the Fragments developer guide.
>   For detailed information about the v13 Support Library APIs, see the
>   android.support.v13 package in the API reference.

Use v4 of support library

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. it turned out that my child fragment extended Fragment. I changed it to extend android.support.v4.app.Fragment and it worked fine.